# link tag in python flask template not working

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a web app where I display a list of website but the problem is that when I click www.example.com, for example, then that website it will not open. Instead

it will append to the localhost:5000/www.example.com

example.com

//Code section

```
     {% for k, v in  diction %}


 <a href="{{ bookKeeping[k]}}"> {{ bookKeeping[k] }}</a></br>


     {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You'd need to show us some code.  At least the snippet of your template containing the link and the python flask method that renders it.  But in general, it sounds like you have <a href="{{somevar}}">{{anothervar}}</a> and you want <a href="http://{{somevar}}">{{anothervar}}</a>.  The logic to add that "http://" should likely be happening in the flask method rather than your template though.

Comment: @clockwatcher  I have added some code

Comment: @clockwatcher that worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Should I use absolute or relative URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/8067842) and [HTML  href Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp).
It should be `<a href="http://{{ bookKeeping[k]}}"> {{ bookKeeping[k] }}</a></br>` for absolute URL.